# how to identify the triggers applyed to (associted with) a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to know the triggers associated with the a particular table in mysql.

I need to delete it so.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

List of associated triggers:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = 'schema_name' AND EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE = 'table_name';
```

Use [DROP TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) command to delete one.